# show element in v-for list: VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-for which display all my items and I have a panel for each items (to modify and delete) but when I click on this button to display my panel, it appears on all of my items. How can I avoid that ? This is the same thing when I click on modify button, the input to modify my item appears on each element.

There is my code :

```
<div v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :list="index" :key="comment">
   <div v-on:click="show = !show">
      <div v-if="show">
         <button @click="edit(comment), active = !active, inactive = !inactive">
            Modify
         </button>
         <button @click="deleteComment(comment)">
            Delete
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p :class="{ active: active }">
        {{ comment.content }}
      </p>
      <input :class="{ inactive: inactive }" type="text" v-model="comment.content" @keyup.enter="doneEdit">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the methods & data :

```
data() {
  return {
    show: false,
    editing: null,
    active: true,
    inactive: true
  }
},

methods: {
   edit(comment) {
     this.editing = comment
     this.oldComment = comment.content
   },

   doneEdit() {
     this.editing = null
     this.active = true
     this.inactive = true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the same `show`, `editing`, `active`, `inactive` state for all items. So if you change some data property for one item it changed for all. 
There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want.

The easiest is to manage your data by index.
For example:

```
<div v-on:click="showIndex = index">
  <div v-if="showIndex === index">
  ...
data () {
  return {
    showIndex: null
  ...
```

The main problem with this approach - you can show/edit only one item at the time. 
If you need more complicated logic and whant to manage more then one item at the time I suggest to create a separate component for your items and each will have own state (`show`, `editing` etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll test that right away !

Answer (score 3):

@NaN's approach works if you want to only have one open at a time. If you want to have the possibility of having multiple open at the same time you would need to keep track of each individual element. Right now you are only basing it on `show`. Which can only be `true/false` for all elements at the same time.

So this is what you need to do:

Change `show` from a boolean to an array

```
data() {
  return {
    show: [],
    editing: null,
    active: true,
    inactive: true,

  }
},
```

Then you can keep track of which element should have the panel or not:

```html
<div v-on:click="toggleActive(index)">
```

And the method:

```js
methods: {
   toggleActive(index) {
      if (this.show.includes(index)) {
        this.show = this.show.filter(entry => entry !== index);

        return; 
      }

      this.show.push(index);
   }
}
```

and finally your `v-if` becomes:

```html
<div v-if="show.includes(index)">
```

Comment: NaN method is a good method, but I'll test your's and decide if I take your's or NaN method, thanks a lot for you answer !